# android studio how to print list of installed apps into a listView

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-package-managers

I've found some code on the internet to obtain details of currently installed apps, I'm not sure how to implement this into a list. I've created the list in the xml file but I'm not too sure how to implement the data into the listView. The code to obtain the app data is -

```
     final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
  mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
  final List pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(      mainIntent, 0);
  for (Object object : pkgAppsList) 
  {
ResolveInfo info = (ResolveInfo) object;
Drawable icon    = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
String strAppName   = info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir.toString();
String strPackageName  = info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName.toString();
final String title  = (String)((info != null) ? getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo) : "???");
```

}

Comment: There is a tutorial and example code [here](http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-get-list-of-installed-apps-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first create a list of String like this:

```
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

then inside your code, add strAppName into the list by `list.add(strAppName);`

and make an array adapter and set it to your listview:

```
    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks, answered my question perfectly. Is there any way I can add the icon into the listview? It's a drawable so it won't allow me to add it in normally next to the app name

Comment: Welcome, you can create a `custom listview`, which use a custom view as item rather than a string. Also look at this: http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/customizing-android-listview-rows-subclassing/